# Processing of the audio file to the transcription using the Azure Cognitive Services SDK | Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, azure

Microsoft has a library for the transcription, but in the official examples only have a microphone input. I want to understand how to transcribe an audio file of wav format.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the Speech API [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-apis) they claim you can only send 10s of recorded audio at a time but @Kasper's question is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-python), it only illustrates how to recognize speech from microphone input.

I think you could try to use custom audio stream,please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-audio-input-streams).

> The Speech SDK's Audio Input Stream API provides a way to stream audio
>   streams into the recognizers instead of using either the microphone or
>   the input file APIs.

However,you need to make sure your format is supported by Azure Speech Service. As the statement in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-audio-input-streams):

> Currently, only the following configuration is supported:
>
> Audio samples in PCM format, one channel, 16000 samples per second,
>   32000 bytes per second, two block align (16 bit including padding for
>   a sample), 16 bits per sample.